# Using htaccess to rewrite unless ending in a file extension

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, file-extension

How would we use the htaccess file to rewrite all URLs to index.php unless they end in a file extension.

The following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Is rewriting everything. If the file ends in .php / .jpg / .css / .js etc.... etc... I would like it not to redirect and instead go to that file.

How is that done?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it but would appreciate some Feedback:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```